# GIT tagging did not work as expected

Tags: git

I have a question about an operation I have done in GIT. I have a repository which has two java projects in it and which currently sits at a certain tag.

```
Project 1 - MyTag 1.0.0
Project 2 - MyTag 1.0.0
```

So far so good.

Yesterday I checked in some code into the head and tagged the code again. Project 1 had some changes in it but Project 2 did not.

After my check in of the changes I tagged the repository again at MyTag 2.0.0. This is what I was expecting to see...

```
Project 1 - MyTag 2.0.0
Project 2 - MyTag 2.0.0
```

But instead I got...

```
Project 1 - MyTag 2.0.0
Project 2 - MyTag 1.0.0
```

Can anyone tell me why Project 2 did not get the new TAG?

I'm using TortoiseGit as my windows GIT client.

thanks

Comment: Did you actually push your new tags to the upstream repository? I don't use TortoiseGit, but from the command line you need to explicitly push tags (`git push --tags`) to have them sent to the server along with the commits.

Comment: Definitely did the push

Answer (score 2):

### Assumptions

1. You have two directories in the root of your git repo, `Project 1`, and `Project 2`. (As an aside, I would suggest splitting these into different repos.)
2. You are expecting that a git Tag will somehow track the state of *all* files
   in a particular commit.

### Answer

Project 2 was included in the tag. What you are seeing is git reporting that the last *commit* made to `Project 2` was the commit pointed to by `MyTag 1.0.0`.

`MyTag 2.0.0` still *includes* `Project 2`.....`Project 2` just hasn't changed since `MyTag 1.0.0`. If you checkout `MyTag 2.0.0` you get a snapshot of the entire repo at that point.

### Background

Tags are *pointers* to a commit. They point either
a) Directly (lightweight tags) or
b) Via a tag object which then points to a commit (annotated tags).

`MyTag 2.0.0` points to a commit (Lets say `C2`) that contains change-sets in `Project 1`. I assume no files in `Project 2` were changed and committed hence the tag doesn't relate *directly* to Project 2's files. `MyTag 1.0.0` also points to a commit (Lets say `C1`).

Since `MyTag 2.0.0` points to `C2` which points to `C1`, all these changes are effectively pointed to by `MyTag 2.0.0`, and will be included when it is checked out.

`MyTag 1.0.0` presumably points to a commit of changes to files in *both* `Project 1/` and `Project 2` directories.

Visually the commits look like this:

```
* C3 ---> C2 ---> C1 ---> init
         /        /
        /        /
  MyTag 2.0.0   /
               /
          MyTag 1.0.0
```

Bear in mind, I'm not using TortoiseGit so I can't see precisely what you are seeing. However the concept I've explained above of how git tags point to commits explains why *any* git client would show a similar result for what you've described. I performed your described commits and tags in a test repo and I get a similar (correct) result in SourceTree.

Comment: There are also annotated tags which are pointers to objects which are pointers to commits.

Comment: Good point - I've edited to be clear that my explanation applies to both kinds of tags. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. So bc my tag only applies to a commit of changes and there were no changes to project 2, the tag does not apply to project 2. Does that mean there is no way to tag a snapshot of what's in the whole repository at any one time unless you commit changes? Seems a real bummer not to b able to do this.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. If both projects are in the same repository then both tags will refer to [some version of] all of the files in both projects. I don't understand how the output 'Project 1 - MyTag 2.0.0 // Project 2 - MyTag 1.0.0' was generated, though.

Comment: @user1600419 I'm not sure why you would want want to store snapshots of the entire repository _including_ **uncommitted** changes. The Tag may not point directly to the commits in Project 2, but by way of reference it certainly includes these commits. I've updated my diagram to reflect that the tag effectively points to the entire history of commits leading up to the one it specifically points to.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, I'm not sure either, but `git log` effectively returns the same result. Referring to my diagram, if some file `f` was changed in C1, but not in C2 or C3, then 'git log f' returns C1 as the last commit and Tag 1.0.0 which points to C1.

Comment: In my scenario I want to tag both projects in the hope that at any one time I can just get the code at a certain tag point. Based on your answer I will now have to track that project 1 tag 2.0.0 goes with project 1.0.0 and checkout accordingly. Would be nice if I could just say get both projects everything at tag 2.0.0. Is my understanding of your answer correct?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure I undersand the issue. You can do exactly what you want. A git checkout of tag 2.0.0 will give you the whole repository in the state it was when you made tag 2.0.0. The most recent commit to the files in your Project 2 just happen to be the commit pointed to by tag 1.0.0. If you had made some other commit between tag 1.0.0 and tag 2.0.0 then you would see THAT commit, and not tag 1.0.0...

Comment: Ahhhh. I understand now. This is what was confusing me. I thought that I would have to checkout project 1 at tag 2.0.0 and project 2 at 1.0.0. So just to reiterate 1 final time what has happened. I've tagged the whole repository at 2.0.0. Bc there were no changes in project 2 it didn't get updated with that tag HOWEVER if I grab the repository code at 2.0.0 it will grab project 1 at 2.0.0 and project 2 at 1.0.0. Have I understood the way it works now?

Comment: Correct! Glad to have helped, c